# Error handling strategy to be used in production

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, web-applications, error-handling

Let's say we have a good but a slightly complex product. The product went wild. Customers are medium and relatively big companies. The level of customers bureaucracy is quite high:

- many different roles and responsibilities
- protected environment
- dozens of rules and policies
- highly specialized engineers (DB-guy belongs to one department, tomcat-guy to another, etc)

With such an approach even a trivial operations(restart and app, get logs, etc) may take hours or even days. Access to logs can be limited or totally prohibited. As I said before, the product is complex, so it is likely there will be some issues during the deployment and initial configuration phase. Which means a customer will  require some assistance and help from the support team.

[image]

**The problem is end-user usually belongs to a R&D department and does not have access to application, application logs, database, etc. In the other word end-user is not able to provide any valuable information at all. Screenshots are the only available feedback.**

**Does anybody know any good solution to this problem?**

The idea is to make customer happy, offload support team and respond promptly on any request. Please also note there are some rules regarding sensitive information, etc.

I see several possible ways for an application to handle an error:

- present high-level problem information with "More details" option, providing sanitized exception or error code
- do the same but also collect some additional information, logs, encrypt it and allow the user to download the file
- provide hidden "service" screen with access to logs and additional system information
- introduce something like a debug mode, to be used on early phases
- finally, permanent access to logs can be requested (personally I think this is unsafe solution).

All these options  are not so good from the usability and security perspectives.

What would you do in such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading some of the things you are considering, and specifically:

- present high-level problem information with "More details" option,
- providing sanitized exception or error code do the same but also
- collect some additional information, logs, encrypt it and allow the
  user to download the file provide hidden "service" screen with access
  to logs and additional system information

What about combining it and make it "safer"?

Modify the code so that an error/exception also creates a sort of "fault ticket" (saving as much extra info as possible) but not showing it to the user.
User will get a "ticket number" (they will have to manually copy it to the mail sent to support, or - if possible, the error message could automatically create a webpage or panel to allow user to add a description of what happened from their point of view, screenshots, and whatever).

This way support will get access to contextualized and richer details (that they can analyze or transfer to the maintenance group without exposing these to the user).
I don't know enough about the internals and the global architecture so I can't judge how complicated this would be to put in place, though.
Ideally every operation should automatically get a "fault ticket" assigned, so that logs will have the correct reference, but the ticket number will be "exposed" only in case of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Once I *had solved* similar issue while working with flexible online "service catalog". Solution was quite simple, but technical *implementation was complex at heterogeneous systems*.

I have to point that, such kind of error detection and tracing is separate cross-cutting concern for your main business domain. So it'll be much better if it's possible to apply this without altering existing source code.

1. Introduce logical *reference* or *correlation* ID for every request/transaction/operation at your system.

   - GUID will be perfect
   - End user will refer to this ID
   - It should be easy to capture this ID on screenshot
   - Make sure that every screen shows this id at page title
2. Use AOP framework (according to your SO profile AspectJ or Spring AOP will be good place to start) to define tracing/logging aspect. Aspect will record information about every call from to web application/business logic/data access layer with correlated reference id

   - To intercept calls use aspects, while reused logging system will persist information
   - As long as you using AOP framework you could configure where tracing/logging happens, what details to be collected at one place
   - Because all tracing/logging are now incapsulated in one place, it's easy to control it using configuration
   - Aspects could be used to escalate some issues immediately via emails, etc
3. Finally, you'll face most complex part. How to make developers and operations don't to ignore information? Such organization issues are out of scope of stackoverflow. In worst case, if it'll take many days to react on an error, you could get production context and lot of details from your logging system

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize and provide more details.

Without any doubt user should be notified in case of an error. The notification should provide high level information regarding the problem. It might be better not only to describe the problem, but also to provide some solution or workaround (if available).

Error dialog should also provide a way to get more information regarding the problem.

[image]

The simplest possible way is to provide sanitized stack trace, relevant log messages, etc. The common scenario for the user is to grab available details and notify support or developers. Obviously, such a solution could not be used to provide all required data, because of the size, sensitive information, etc.

[image]

As an option, system can send that information directly to support/error collecting tool. Secure channel can be used to protect the data. If needed, collection tool may reside within customers network, so sensitive information will never go out.

If such an option is not available the system can let the user to download archive with all required information. Archive can be encrypted to make sure ordinary user (facing the problem) will not be able to examine potentially sensitive data.

[image]

Naturally, it is better not to use a hard-coded passwords, so more advanced approach can be used. Scenario is the following:

1. system presents error message
2. system generates error id and uses it to generate some unique value (a hash)
3. user contacts support and tells unique value
4. support uses that value to generate the code
5. user receives the code from support
6. user downloads the archive with all details (encrypted)
7. user passes downloaded information to support

[image]

Looks a like a paranoid solution, but allows to control access to potentially sensitive information.

**Finall conclusion**

Logging strategy should be well-developed. Sensitive information should not be logged.

**Useful links**

- [Effective logging practices ease enterprise development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-logging/)
- [Strategies to Mitigate Targeted Cyber Intrusions Part-1](http://www.dsd.gov.au/infosec/top-mitigations/top35mitigation-details.htm)
- [Strategies to Mitigate Targeted Cyber Intrusions Part-2](http://www.dsd.gov.au/infosec/top-mitigations/top35mitigationstrategies-list.htm)

Comment: "The common scenario for the user is to grab available details and notify support or developers" why? You are *forcing* the users to collect something that is useless for them and make sure it reaches support. Encrypted, even... just save the encrypted bundle server side, and provide the user just a unique id that can be also spelled over the phone, mentioned in an email etc.

Comment: I fully agree. It is really better to hide any "support specific" stuff from the user. The situation I'm describing is a little bit trickier: support does not have access to the product at all. So I'm not trying to force user to do something stupid. Quite the contrary, I'm trying to save some users time, because currently user is supposed to reproduce the problem while doing screen sharing and then ask administrator to provide some logs. Encryption is needed, to make sure user will not be able to do some unwanted analysis. Smaller evil, let's say.